# Find first digit of a number using ONLY integer operations

Tags: c#, math

I can't understand how to solve the problem that the teacher gave me.

> Given a number N (0 <= N <= 100), find its **first** digit.

For example:

```
input: 100
result: 1

input: 46
result: 4

input: 3
result: 3
```

It seemed easy at first, but (as the teacher said) it should be done using **ONLY** integer data types (in other words, using `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%` operators). Is it even possible to do it this way?

I just can't realize how to extract the first digit from a *variable-length* number without using things like log10, conditions, "while" loop or string conversion.

Comment: Is it **required** to not use loops?

Comment: In given range `(0 <= N <= 100)` it is possible with two `if` and in any range it is possible using loop. _(Sorry, since it is a homework, no real solution.)_

Comment: a loop is not changing the datatype, what your professor want you to avoid is n.ToString()[0]

Comment: @Tau yes, it should be done using only stated above operators. I know how to use loops and stuff, but we just started to study C# and couldn't know about loops and conditions according to the curriculum. Maybe this curriculum is broken a bit? idk. The teacher rejected my solutions with `while` loop and via `Math.Log10()`.

Comment: @PhantomLobster; Maybe he didn't reject the while loop in general but just the way you did it(for example with string conversions). It would have breen great if you'd have shown your approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that may sound stupid, but she clearly said "no loops, conditions & stuff" to me, "only operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%`". I'm in real confusion, so I posted this question here. @mjwills Sorry, but no.

Comment: I'm starting to think this problem just shouldn't be in subject "Integers" we studied last lesson and got there by lack of attention or smth :(

Comment: @mjwills we just studied integer data types, so ternary operator isn't allowed for sure

Comment: @PhantomLobster just replace it with an `if/else` then

Comment: @Rafalon I'm allowed to use only `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%`, so no `if-else` statements. I'm not sure this is even possible to do this way :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** Now tested for 0 and 100:

```
var result = n / 10 * (1 - n / 100) + n / 100 + (109 - n) / 100 * n;
```

How it works:

```
n        | n / 10 * (1 - n / 100) | n / 100 | (109 - n) / 100 * n
-----------------------------------------------------------------
10 - 99  | 1 - 9                  | 0       | 0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
100      | 0                      | 1       | 0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0 - 9    | 0                      | 0       | 0 - 9
```

Comment: What about N = 0 ?

Comment: Thank you for help! I think I'll stick to this solution because it looks a bit less complicated for me than @YvesDaoust 's option :)

Answer (score 10):

**Without any conditionals:**

```
int H= N / 100;       // Hundreds digit
int T= (N / 10) % 10; // Tens digit
int U= N % 10;        // Units digit

int h= H;                      // Hundreds flag
int t= (T + 9) / 10 * (1 - h); // Tens flag
int u= (1 - t) * (1 - h);      // Units flag

int Answer= u * U + t * T + h * H; // Combination
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a while loop, and keep dividing the input number by 10, so long as we are starting with a value which is *greater* than or equal to 10.  When the modified input is less than ten, then it means we have stripped off all digits to the right, except for the "first" digit.

```
int input = 100;

while (input >= 10)
{
    input /= 10;
}

Console.WriteLine("First digit is: {0}", input);
```

### Demo

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not allowed to use loops, conditions, etc. in this homework. Only `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%`. I'm not sure that this is even possible :(

Comment: @PhantomLobster You could use recursion instead, which wouldn't involve any _explicit_ loops.  See a few of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-generic response, and only works because the domain is limited. The idea is to return all the digits (hundred's, ten's, and one's) smooshed together." Some thoughts on specific ranges of numbers:

100 is easy because the ten's and one's units are both zero. There are no other three digit numbers, which is good, because anything with a non-zero one's or ten's place will cause problems below.

All numbers less than 100 can include the hundred's digit in the response because it will always be zero.

Any multiple of 10 is easy, just include the each hundred's ten's and one's value, because the other digits are zero.

The tricky part is the one's place. There needs to be a way to "cancel out" this value if a larger digit is supposed to be returned. For example, 87, we want the 8 but want to cancel out the 7.

This leads to the idea

```
(ten - 9)*(ten - 8)*(ten - 7)*(ten - 6)*(ten - 5)*(ten - 4)*(ten - 3)*(ten - 2)*(ten - 1)
```

What happens is that any time the ten's place is non-zero, the above will evaluate to zero. So we can multiply the one's place by this to zero out the one's place when the ten's place is non-zero. However, there's a problem when the ten's place is zero. In that case, we're off by a factor of 9! (nine factorial = 362880) and the wrong sign. This is why an extra minus sign is included, and divide out by 362880 to get the right answer when ten's place is zero.

```
public int GetFirstDigit(int n)
{
    var hundred = (n % 1000) / 100;
    var ten = (n % 100) / 10;
    var one = n % 10;

    return hundred + ten + one*
    (
    -(ten - 9)*(ten - 8)*(ten - 7)*(ten - 6)*(ten - 5)*(ten - 4)*(ten - 3)*(ten - 2)*(ten - 1)
    ) / 362880
    ;
}
```

check with

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 101).ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x + ": " + GetFirstDigit(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int Result(int input)
{
    return input/100 + (input%100/input)*input/10 + (input%10/input)*input;
}
```

- `input/100` will return 1 if and only if `input` equals 100, else 0
- `(input%100/input)` will return 1 if and only if `input < 100`,  else 0

  - if `input` is lower than 10, `input/10` will be 0
- `(input%10/input)` will return 1 if and only if `input < 10`, else 0

### Caution

This would break if `input == 0`, see [@quanik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52500305/7831383) to handle 0.

However, it will work for 1-999.

Comment: @quanik I actually had a hard time with that last part, until I realized this would work

Comment: @YvesDaoust I realized it and edited my answer 33 seconds before you commented

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the case but without success,
I can only achieve finding the first digit if the N is 1 - 100.
Here is my source code for it. Hope it helps
https://dotnetfiddle.net/6XyOfd

Comment: @Pretasoc thanks for reviewing, yeah my bad it only works for 10 - 99